# IEEEeqnarray hyperlinks to a group of subnumbered equations

Tags: hyperref, ieeetran

When I use IEEEeqnarray subnumbering and the hyperref package, hyperrefs to the subnumbered equations work fine; but if I try to reference the group of equations, the label is not found.

Example document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
When I create an IEEEeqnarray with subequation numbering and try to point back to the group of equations, the hyperrefs are broken.

\newpage

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}\label{eqn:FirstParentLabel}
f(x) &=& 5x \IEEEyesnumber\IEEEyessubnumber\label{eqn:FirstSubeqnLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}\IEEEyesnumber\label{eqn:SecondParentLabel}
g(x) &=& \pi \IEEEyesnumber\IEEEyessubnumber\label{eqn:SecondSubeqnLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
h(x) &=& 42 \IEEEyesnumber\label{eqn:ThirdParentLabel}\IEEEyessubnumber\label{eqn:ThirdSubeqnLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
k(x) &=& C \label{eqn:FourthLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\newpage

References to subequations work: \ref{eqn:FirstSubeqnLabel},\ref{eqn:SecondSubeqnLabel}, and \ref{eqn:ThirdSubeqnLabel}.  But references to groups of equations do not work: \ref{eqn:FirstParentLabel}, \ref{eqn:SecondParentLabel}, and \ref{eqn:ThirdParentLabel}.  If I don't use subnumbering everything works fine: \ref{eqn:FourthLabel}.

\end{document}
```

I'm using TexLive 2012 and the most recent version of IEEEtrantools.sty.  Compiler error messages are emitted:
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{equation.0.0.3} ha
s been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{equation.0.0.2} has been referenced but does not ex
ist, replaced by a fixed one

pdfTeX warning (dest): name{equation.0.0.1} has been referenced but does not ex
ist, replaced by a fixed one

Any ideas why this would be?  I can't think of any more permutations on the attempts shown above.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place a definitive marker - `\phantomsection` - *after* every `\IEEEyesnumber` in order to mark the appropriate hypertarget:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}\IEEEyesnumber\phantomsection\label{eqn:FirstParentLabel}
f(x) &=& 5x \IEEEyessubnumber\label{eqn:FirstSubeqnLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}\IEEEyesnumber\phantomsection\label{eqn:SecondParentLabel}
g(x) &=& \pi \IEEEyessubnumber\label{eqn:SecondSubeqnLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}\IEEEyesnumber\phantomsection\label{eqn:ThirdParentLabel}
h(x) &=& 42 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{eqn:ThirdSubeqnLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
k(x) &=& C \label{eqn:FourthLabel}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

`\IEEEyessubnumber` will override the use of `\IEEEyesnumber` in terms of the label display. However, at this point, the `\phantomsection` placement has already established an appropriate (different) hypertarget than what will follow with the sub-equation `\label`.